# Declaring array before main

Tags: c, arrays

C language - I don't understand why

this works:

```
#define x 5
int vett[x];
main () {}
```

this works:

```
int vett[5];
main () {}
```

this works:

```
main () {
   int x=5;
   int vett[x];
}
```

this works:

```
int x=5;
main () {
   int vett[x];
}
```

this does NOT work:

```
int x=5;
int vett[x];
main () {}
```

Comment: global arrays require a constant size.  Is there a question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all other examples the size of the array is initialized with a constant (5) when outside main.
In the last example the initialization of the array is outside of main so it is not running code, the compiler does not know what the value of x is.